# Solve a homogeneous differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $0\leq a\leq 1$. I want to solve the diferrential equation $2(1-2a)y''x^2-2ay=0$. My idea is to consider a solution of the form $y=A_1x^{r_1}+A_1x^{r_2}$. Then $r_1$ and $r_2$ are solutions to $2(1-2a)r(r-1)-2a=0$. The problem arises when $a>\frac{1}{2}$, and the previous equation doesn't have real rools. I want to ask which method can I use to characterize the solution to the differential equation when $a>\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2(1-2a)y''x^2-2ay=0$$
It's [Cauchy- Euler's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation)

For $y_1=x^{r_1}$ where $r$ is complex you can write:
$$y_1=x^{c+id}=x^ce^{id \ln x}$$
$$y_1=x^c(\cos {(d \ln x)+i\sin (d \ln x))}$$
For $y_2=x^{r_2}$:
$$y_2=x^c(\cos {(d \ln x)-i\sin (d \ln x))}$$
where $r_1=c+id$ and $r_2=c-id$

So that the general solution is:
$$y=x^c(k_1\cos {(d \ln x)+k_2\sin (d \ln x))}$$